# IEnumerable definition is rerun everytime the IEnumerable object is invoked, leading to first item being set to nothing when there is only one item

Tags: vb.net, datatable, ienumerable

I am trying to limit my data table (_dtMain) to be items that in "myColumn" equal myValue.
The code below generally works fine, except when IEnumerable en has only one datarow. In that case, en(0) seems to be set to nothing. Perhaps it is on the line of code that it is being set to nothing: If en.Count < 1 OrElse en(0) Is Nothing Then Return String.Empty

This seems strange to me, but that's what appears to happen during debugging.

I also happened to notice, when debugging, that the top line of code below is called whenever en is invoked, such as in the second and third lines of code. I did not expect this behavior. Obviously, I'm missing something about how this IEnumerable behaves.

Any light shed on how this is working, and how to avoid en(0) to be set to nothing when there is only one row in en, would be appreciated.

```
Dim en As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = _dtMain.AsEnumerable.Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("MyColumn") = myValue).DefaultIfEmpty
If en.Count < 1 OrElse en(0) Is Nothing Then Return String.Empty
Dim dtMyColumn As DataTable = en.CopyToDataTable
```

Comment: Odd. I closed the application and reran in debug and it worked this time. Does the definition always get run whenever using the IEnumerable in the code? And, does it lead to flaky behavior?

Comment: Why don't you set the [DefaultView.RowFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter) instead? Or do you plan to ditch `_dtMain` after?

Comment: Linq functions like `Where` will usually return deferred execution enumerations whenever possible, so `en` will re-process the filter every time you access it.  The behavior is only "flaky" if you don't anticipate it.

Comment: @Jimi Yes. I ditch _dtMain immediately after.